# Where is the data folder for Bitcoin-Qt?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, datadir, bitcoincore-gui

Where can I find the blockchain, wallet.dat, etc. on each of the operating systems [Bitcoin-Qt](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin-Qt) supports?

Comment: I see questions which answer this for particular operating systems, but would like an answer to be able to point to that works for any supported OS.

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1350/659 has the OSX path.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, but asking about how to change the default storage location has been posted many, many times. The future canonical question is probably *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*.

Comment: To be fair I asked this almost a year before that other question was asked.

Comment: Also the question you linked to doesn't have any information that answers my question. There's no mention on the MacOS path, for instance.

Comment: For Ubuntu or Linux installs with snap, it's at ~/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is the same [data folder](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory) as the non-QT version of the standard client used to use:

**Linux:**

`~/.bitcoin/`

**MacOS:**

`~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`

**Windows:**

`%APPDATA%\Bitcoin`

(This defaults to `C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Application data\Bitcoin` on Windows XP and to `C:\Users\YourUserName\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin` on Windows Vista, 7, 8, and 10.)

Comment: On English versions of Windows I presume(?)

Comment: Also have English version and no Bitcoin folder there

Comment: It might be worth noting that it is also possible to specify a custom data directory, using the -datadir=<path-to-folder> option from command line.
This actually allows to have multiple running instances of bitcoin: you just need to run bitcoind/bitcoin-qt twice, specifying two different data folders.

Answer (score 6):

On the new Mac OS X you can't see the Bitcoin folder in the library under /application support/. You have to use Finder and in the menu look for GO and then GO TO type `~/Library` in the box. After that you can see the Bitcoin folder under /application support/.

Or you can hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while selecting the *Go* menu and *Library* will become an option.

Comment: This works as of June 2018

Answer (score 2):

On windows8, the data folder is here:

C:\Users\ ... your user name ...\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\

Comment: So exactly like Windows 7?

Comment: I also have Windows 7 and no Bitcoin folder there

Answer (score 2):

[@ThePiachu](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/323/thepiachu) is right

> **Linux:**
>
> `~/.bitcoin/`
>
> **macOS:**
>
> `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`
>
> **Windows:**
>
> `%APPDATA%\Bitcoin`

But since there are no instructions, it may be hard for a user to find them, so I'm going to add instructions.

## macOS

1) Click the Finder symbol

[image]

2) Press <kbd>command (cmd) ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>option (alt) ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> at the same time.

3) Paste this into the window that opens:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/
```

[image]

4) Press "Go"

5) That's your Bitcoin folder!

## Windows

1) Choose one of your folders, and open it (we won't do anything with the folder, so it doesn't matter if it's very important for you).

2) Click the folder icon next to the file location.

[image]

3) Paste the following:

```
%APPDATA%\Bitcoin
```

4) Press <kbd>Enter ⏎</kbd>

5) That's your Bitcoin folder!