# How to keep Bitcions when reinstalling OS from fresh

Tags: wallet, client, backup

I have the official Bitcoin wallet and I would like to do a fresh install of everything on the computer. How can I save my Bitcoins (and hopefully block chain)?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @GregHewgill Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

(I suppose you have the Bitcoin-Qt client.)

Taking a backup of the [Bitcoin folder](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/where-is-the-data-folder-for-bitcoin-qt) will do it.

- Copy the folder to an external hard drive of a different partition.
- Reinstall your system.
- Install Bitcoin-Qt again.
- Move the folder back.

Note that to keep your bitcoins, only the `wallet.dat` file is required. But when you copy the whole folder, you will probably not need to sync with the network again.