# How can I create a new wallet on Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, wallet.dat

How can I create a new wallet on Bitcoin Core (Bitcoin QT)? I forgot my old password, so I can't create transactions using the old wallet. I don't have money on my old wallet, I just need to create new wallet without the forgotten password.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bitcoin Core will create a new wallet if it cannot find the `wallet.dat` in the Bitcoin Core folder.

1. Close Bitcoin Core.
2. If the wallet still has a balance, or addresses from the wallet were given out, **back the old `wallet.dat` up**: Move it to a different directory or rename it. If you are sure that it was never used, you may delete it instead.
3. Restart Bitcoin Core. A new wallet will be created.

If you don't know where to find the `wallet.dat`, check here: [Where is the data folder for bitcoin-qt?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4006/5406)

Comment: Would be nice to have a reference to where to find this in the bitcoin core code

Comment: So, a new wallet is created each time we open Core?

Comment: The first time it doesn't find a `wallet.dat`, it will create one, and then there will be one, so it won't create another.

Answer (score 4):

With bitcoin-core version 0.21, [*A default wallet is no longer automatically created*](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/4132193617a31394933c748bbdc1f441a21a39b4/test/functional/wallet_multiwallet.py#L261)

Here is the command to create a new wallet.

```
$ bitcoin-wallet -wallet=wallet.dat create
Topping up keypool...
Wallet info
===========
Name: wallet.dat
Format: bdb
Descriptors: no
Encrypted: no
HD (hd seed available): yes
Keypool Size: 2000
Transactions: 0
Address Book: 0
(BTC) ➜  Wallets
```

Then start the bitcoin-core by specifying the wallets, for instance:

```
$ bitcoind -server -walletdir=/home/netsamir/.bitcoin/wallets/wallet.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can create a new wallet within the GUI with "File" > "Create Wallet...".