# Bitcoin.conf not being read by Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, php

My issue is I cannot get RPC working with Bitcoin Core. I do not know what I'm doing wrong! When I first installed Bitcoin Core it did not come with a bitcoin.conf file so I created one with the following details:

```
server=1
rpcuser=root
rpcpassword=password
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8332
```

That's all I have in there. And yes my Bitcoin Core client is in sync with the bitcoin network.

I've also checked my router and it is UPNP enabled and I literally see the port in my router's configuration open. The port is: 8333

And it is the only port open. Do not know if I need 8332 open. Please shed some light on this for me. What I am trying to accomplish is to get PHP to interact with bitcoind such as generate a new bitcoin address.

Comment: Is the script trying to generate a new address on the same computer as the bitcoin client?

Comment: Have you tried adding `rpcallow=127.0.0.1`?

Comment: One possibility is that your bitcoin.conf is not in the directory where Bitcoin Core expects it to be.

Comment: @StephenM347 127.0.0.1 is automatically whitelisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to simply move bitcoin.conf in the correct directory, as described here: [Where is the data folder for Bitcoin-Qt?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/where-is-the-data-folder-for-bitcoin-qt)
Also, don't forget to set the correct file permissions as well; `bitcoin.conf` should be owner **read-only**!