# Unconfirmed BTC transaction / TXID doesn't exist?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, coinbase.com, mempool, transaction-id

I recently tried sending some btc to coinbase.  In a hurry I did not put a transaction fee.  I've tried to explain to their customer support what is going on.  I offered to charge me a fee through my wallet on coinbase to do a pay for parent protocol. Their lack of understanding is making me worry.  I tried using ViaBTC.  I put in the transaction ID and they said the TXID did not exist.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Its approaching 7 days now.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you literally set a fee of zero?  Such transactions are normally not relayed, so it would be normal if coinbase never saw it.  If you can tell your wallet software to just forget the transaction, then you can simply create a new one (spending the same inputs) that does have a fee.

Comment: how do i resend with the same inputs?  I am using bitcoin qt 4.8.3. It has been 7 days now.  Not confirmed.  I mentioned cpfp and asked them to bill my account accordingly, I don't think they even understand what I am talking about.  Its all pre programmed email responses.  I am worried coinbase is going to change my coinbase btc wallet address.  This is my second btc transaction with them and my second coinbase btc wallet address.  I think thats how messed up they are.  Any suggestions?

Comment: See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it.  Note that 4.8.3 is incredibly ancient and it would be wise to upgrade.  It is not a problem if they change your wallet address, this is normal and desirable. Just use the new one for the destination of the new transaction.

Comment: so just resend it?  What happens to the original transaction?  Will my btc qt wallet be credited from the original transaction?

Comment: As far as the blockchain is concerned, the original transaction never existed and the funds never left your wallet.  You just have to convince your own wallet to forget about the original transaction as well, so that it has the same view as the rest of the world.  Then you can create a new transaction.  It's good to make sure that the inputs of the original transaction are spent, to avoid any possibility of some attacker resurrecting the original transaction in the future - as mentioned in the linked answer, this can be done by simply sending your entire balance to yourself.

Comment: so i would have to send my entire balance plus the original transaction to myself (the same bitcoin qt wallet) and that would credit my bitcoin qt wallet?  Will it allow me too?

Comment: I'm really upset with coinbase at this point.  They are supposed to be this major corporation.  They don't have a mining rig in their engineering department?  Or they don't offer cpfp?  I might not be the brightest bulb in the chandelier but I know you get better results on market places on the dark web.  Mark Andreesen and Horowitz should be ashamed of themselves.  I could have gotten better results from a kid in his mother's basement in the third world than this multi million dollar company in the west (so they claim). Smh

Comment: I don't believe CPFP is even possible with a zero-fee transaction.  The parent will never be relayed, so miners won't ever see it, and they can't confirm the child without it, no matter how high the fee is.  And having "a mining rig" isn't sufficient to get a transaction confirmed, not unless you want to wait an indefinite amount of time.  Anyway, I get that you're upset, but the comments thread here should be kept relevant to the technical question at hand, not for general venting.

Comment: If you zap transactions and rescan as explained in the other question I linked above, then your wallet will not know anything about the original transaction ever having existed.  You will see the same balance you had before you sent it.  At that point, you can generate a new address with your wallet and send your entire balance there (with a fee!) - that will ensure the original transaction can never confirm.  Then you can finally send funds to coinbase (using a current deposit address) or wherever else you please.

Comment: I understand, just want to let the community know of that coinbase's customer support is basically outsourced to stackexchange.  Could you help me though?  I am trying to get my bitcoin qt 4.8.3 wallet/node back to whole.  It is still debited that unconfirmed transaction.  What should I do?

Comment: zap transactions? rescan? How do I actually do that though?  I will go over your previous answers.  And really appreciate everything you have already done.

Comment: **Read the answers to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it as I linked above**, particularly https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/22365/5757 which explains exactly how to do this.

Comment: How do I Run bitcoind and with -zapwallettxes.?

Comment: From the command line, e.g. `./bitcoind -zapwallettxes`.  This is my last reply.

Comment: method not found (-32601)

Comment: Thank you though for what you could do.  I'll keep reading.

Answer (score 1):

In any case, receiver (Coinbase) can't do much to make your transaction confirm faster. Except [CPFP](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/cpfp), but you can do the same with your change output, if you have it. But, as mentioned above, if tx fee really is 0, it will not be relayed by the network, as default relay fee is 1 satoshi per vbyte. Also, in 7 days it should have been confirmed, as mempool clears out regularly at the moment. I bet you will not see that transaction by txid in any public block explorer either. So, you should just send them again from the wallet you initially send them out.

Comment: how do i resend with the same inputs?  I am using bitcoin qt 4.8.3. It has been 7 days now.  Not confirmed. I mentioned cpfp and asked them to bill my account accordingly, I don't think they even understand what I am talking about.  Its all pre programmed email responses.  I still would like the transaction to go through and my coinbase account credited.  I am worried coinbase is going to change my coinbase btc wallet address.  This is my second btc transaction with them and my second coinbase btc wallet address.  I think thats how messed up they are.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need exactly the same inputs? Because of potential double spend risks? There is coin control button in Send tab or bitcoin-qt, where you can select individual UTXO's.

Comment: I have a bitcoin qt node/wallet 4.8.3 I'd like it to show that I have that unconfirmed transaction back.  At this point my wallet is debited, I'd like to make it whole.  What should I do?

Comment: Have no idea what is 4.8.3, latest release of bitcoin-qt is 0.18.1. https://bitcoincore.org/

Comment: Updating now. Syncing to the network. See what happens. Not to confident I will get the results I'm looking for. With 0.18.1 can I cancel the unconfirmed transaction? Or will it just sync correctly? Don't know, will find out later in the day.

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54284/how-do-i-get-rid-of-an-unconfirmed-transaction-on-bitcoin-core-0-14-1