# bitcoin.conf file on mac

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin.conf, bitcoin-qt-setup

I have installed bitcoin core on mac and accessed the config file from the preferences tab on the bitcoin-qt.

Now, I have started testnet on it by the below settings.

```
testnet=1
server=1
rpcuser=xxxxx
rpcpassword=xxxxxx
rpctimeout=30000
rpcport=8332
```

I was able to run it properly. so I thought of accessing the RPC from other systems, so I have assigned a public IP to it and in the config file, I have mentioned

```
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0
```

Now, I tried starting qt on my mac but unable to start it as it throws `Invalid -rpcallowip subnet specification` and I could not open the preferences tab and then open the configuration file.

I have tried to access the folder directly by going to the location `'~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/'` but there was no folder named `Bitcoin` in my mac.

Is there any other location, where it would be?

I have searched the entire system using bitcoin.conf but found no results.

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: How did you put that config file (the top snippet) if there was non in that folder? The subnet specification might mean that you need to add a `/n` suffix to the IP, like `0.0.0.0/0`. This is useful to allow all on local network, like this `192.168.0.0/24`.

Comment: Hello @StevenRoose : thanks for the reply. I've done it from bitcoin qt where there is an option to open configuration file from preferences tab.

Comment: Finally I found an answer using this comment [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/4359/60371)

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to solve a similar issue of modifying the config file through the preference tab and then I could not launch Bitcoin Qt anymore.

The bitcoin.config file is located here /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin

But you need to go to the Finder app and hit <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> first to show hidden folders and files.