# How do I delete the blockchain after uninstalling Bitcion Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, datadir

I downloaded bitcoin core, and it "synced" the blockchain, taking up 163gig on my HD considerably slowing my comp. so I uninstalled bitcoin core, but yet still see to have 163gig of unwanted data slowing my computer. I operate Windows 10. HOW do I get rid of it. It seems to be in my users file, but mysteriously doesn't show up when trying to locate it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to delete your data directory.

See the question [Where is the data folder for Bitcoin-Qt?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/where-is-the-data-folder-for-bitcoin-qt) for where it should be installed by default on your system.

Make sure you backup `wallet.dat` first, if you've ever used any of the addresses in your wallet.