# Having trouble finding wallet.dat

Tags: wallet, mining-pools, electrum

[Where is the data folder for Bitcoin-Qt?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/where-is-the-data-folder-for-bitcoin-qt)

Windows:

%APPDATA%\Bitcoin

(This defaults to C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Application data\Bitcoin on Windows XP and to C:\Users\YourUserName\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin on Windows Vista, 7, 8, and 10.)

Whereas mine looks like this:

C:\Users\YourUserName\Appdata\

Then my choices are:

local, local low, roaming,

If I click roaming I get Identities- In this folder is a sequence of 32 characters starting with E9. Microsoft- within there are folders named Credentials- empty MMC- empty Crypto- has a rsa file. System certificates- has empty folders. A file called protect- has a sequence of characters stating with s1. Windows folder- contains more folders and files.

I have two appdata folders, one has a swf and a docwrite file and the other is described above.

There is a dat file in local but it isn’t a walletdat.